# How to append XML node to HTML DOM in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, dom

I'm trying to append XML node to HTML DOM in IE <8 and I keep getting `Object doesn't support property or method appendChild` error but works fine on latest browsers. Is there another way of appending XML element in DOM?

I also tried putting `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`

I want to append XML element not as string like the image below.
[image]

```js
var jObj = { "Smart Shoes":{  
          "Product":"Smart Shoes",
          "Price":24.99,
          "Quantity":"1x "
       },
       "Denim Jeans":{  
          "Product":"Denim Jeans",
          "Price":30,
          "Quantity":"1x "
       }
    };

    var xml = document.createElement("xml");
        xml.setAttribute("id", "POSCMD");
        xml.setAttribute("LateProcessing", "true");
        var commands = document.createElement("commands");
        xml.appendChild(commands);
        var injFM = document.createElement("injectfieldmacro");
        injFM.setAttribute("type", "field");
        injFM.setAttribute("name", "FIELD_CLEAR");
        commands.appendChild(injFM);
        var injData;
        for (var item in jObj) {
            injData = document.createElement("injectdata");
            injData.setAttribute("type", "literal");
            injData.setAttribute("data", JSON.stringify(jObj[item].Product));
            injFM = document.createElement("injectfieldmacro");
            injFM.setAttribute("type", "field");
            injFM.setAttribute("name", "FIELD_UPC");
            commands.appendChild(injData);
            commands.appendChild(injFM);
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(xml);
```

Comment: You should stop supporting IE7

Comment: If I could I would but, this javascript is for web-call outs POS system. Which I believe uses IE artefact.

Comment: So for which statement exactly do you get that error message?

Comment: @MartinHonnen just `appendChild` function doesn't seems to work on old IE.

Comment: `appendChild()` has support in IE6+, To me `JSON.stringify()` can create problem

Comment: Can you add a code snippet allowing us to reproduce the problem? I don't see why `appendChild` should not work and in particular why the error message should then say "method append" instead of `appendChild`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Will create a fiddle, yeah that's my typo error it meant `appendChild`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen is creating the snippet here, enough?

Comment: @Satpal is there another way of using `JSON.stringify` on older IE?

Comment: See https://bestiejs.github.io/json3/

Comment: Stackoverflow allows you to create and insert executable Javascript snippets, so yes, of course show us what you have to allow us to reproduce it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I've created a snippet here. I get this as well `Unexpected call to method or property access.`

Comment: I think the problem is that the element you have create first with `document.createElement("xml")` in old versions of IE has a special meaning, it creates a so called XML data island which is basically a HTML element exposing an MSXML DOM for XML data. So that can't work as it does in current versions of IE or other browsers where the `document.createElement("xml")` on the HTML document just creates an unknow element. Do you have to named that element `xml`?

Comment: I tried changing that `document.createElement("xml")` to something else like `document.createElement("product")` but still not rendering, I `console.log()` it and it says `Object UnknownHTML Element`

Comment: What kind of "rendering" do you expect for an unknown HTML element only having attribute data? When I run your posted code snippet in current browsers they don't render anything, they just put that element into the body.

Comment: well not rendering any data into the body, but appending the `<xml></xml>` element into the body like the image I included in my original post.

Comment: I think that old IE versions will insert that `document.createElement('product')` element into the HTML DOM fine, you will have to insert a patch for `JSON.stringify` to get your code to work.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I added json3 `JSON.parse()` instead as @Satpal suggested in the link he gave.

Comment: I can append it as a `.innerText()` or `.text()` but not as a XML node which is the one I need.